If existence of a pre-isomorphism implies existence of an isomorphism, would AC follow?
Let a surjection $f: M \to N$ be called a pre-isomorphism on membership, if and only if:
$\begin{align} \forall x \in M \,\forall y \in M \,\exists x' \in M \exists y' \in M : \  &  f(x')=f(x) \land  f(y')=f(y) \ \land \\& ( x' \in y' \leftrightarrow f(x) \in f(y) )  \end{align}$
Now using axiom of choice one can easily prove that for any distinct sets if there exists a pre-isomorphism between them then there exists an isomorphism between them.

Is the converse true? That is, if the existence of a pre-isomorphism between two sets implies they are isomorphic, would $\sf AC$ follow?


You say

Now using axiom of choice one can easily prove that for any distinct sets if there exists a pre-isomorphism between them then there exists an isomorphism between them.

But this is not true. Take $M$ to be $V_\omega$, for example, but actually any set with at least two elements will work, and let $N=\{0\}$ be a one-element set. Define $f:M\to N$ to be constant. So $f(x)\in f(y)$ is always false. But for every $x$ and $y$ there is some $x'$ and $y'$ with $x'\notin y'$. So we have $f(x)=f(x')$, $f(y)=f(y')$, and $x'\in y'\leftrightarrow f(x)\in f(y)$. So this is a pre-isomorphism, but there is no isomorphism.
Since this example exists in ZF, then answer to your question is vacuously yes, AC would follow, since the assumption is inconsistent.
